# subprocess.Popen and buffered process output

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran

From inside python code, I want to run a binary program that gets its parameters from stdin. Using the subprocess module, this should be straightforward:

```
import subprocess
command = [ 'my_program' ]
p = subprocess.Popen( command,  \
        stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, \
        env={ "GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL": "1"} )
p.stdin.write ( stdin_stuff )
while True:
  o = p.stdout.readline()
  if p.poll() != None: 
    break
  # Do something with stdout
```

Now, this launches the program, but the python script just hangs there. I understand that this may well be due gfortran (which I use to compile my_program is buffering its stdout stream. gfortran allows one to use the GFORTRAN_UNBUFFERED_ALL environmental variable, as I have done, as well as using the FLUSH() intrinsic in the fortran code, but still no luck: the python code still hangs.

Comment: You can accept an answer you like by "checking" the mark next to it.  It is considered polite on this site to do so, so you might want to check the answers you like best on the questions you have asked.

Answer (score 4):

You should have better luck using [`Popen.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to send strings to the process' `stdin` rather than manually writing to it.

```
stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate(stdin_stuff)
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Aphex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947782/subprocess-popen-and-buffered-process-output/4947834#4947834), here the relevant part of the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> Warning
>
> Use `communicate()` rather than `.stdin.write`, `.stdout.read` or `.stderr.read` to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Comment: This might be better served as an update to @Aphex or a comment.  It doesn't seem like a good answer all by itself like this.

Comment: @S.Lott: Thought about making it a comment, but the formatting really doesn't work as a comment.  That's why I explicitly stated it's a complement to Aphex's answer.

Comment: "the formatting really doesn't work as a comment".  True.  Why not an update?

Comment: The `input` argument to `communicate` is a plain string, not a stream, so if the input data might be large, put it in a producer thread. If the output data might be large, read incrementally from the output as in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14026178/33208).